# Passing data between components issue

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to pass information from one component to another and information from that component back again.

I am just wondering what is the best way to do this.

I have tried to use an EventEmitter but seem to be coming across some issues:

There is a Input box that on every key press I want it to call the other component with the current value in the box:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" #box (keyup)="searchValueChanged(box.value)"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search for an Application..."/>
```

JS:

```
@Output() messageEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

searchValueChanged(value:string) {
  this.messageEvent.emit(value);
  console.log(value);
}
```

Then in the other component I am trying to receive the message:

HTML:

```
<app-menu-top (messageEvent)="receiveMessage(value)"></app-menu-top>
```

JS:

```
receiveMessage(value) {
  this.message = value;
  console.log(this.message);
}
```

1. Is this the best way for me to be passing data?
2. How come 'value' seem to be undefined (empty)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its normal to use this style to pass data from one component into another. One solution also can be to use singleton service and observable into it.

What about `undefined` - change `value` into the `$event`

```
<app-menu-top (messageEvent)="receiveMessage($event)"></app-menu-top>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. I was nearly there! Is this approach good if there needs to be information passed between both components?

Answer (score 0):

From Angular docs, [Recipes for common component communication scenarios](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)